# asp.net MVC : capture Html.BeginForm with different action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I render a view through my controller like so:

```
public ViewResult Forum([DefaultValue(0)]int id)
        {
            ForumMessagesViewModel forumMsgs = new ForumMessagesViewModel(_articles.GetAllForumMessages());
            return View(forumMsgs);
        }
```

Inside that view .aspx, I want to enable message posting. So I created the following form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddForumMessage", "Home"))
       { %>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>add message</legend>

                    <label id="NameLabel">name:</label>
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newMessage.MessagePosterName) %>      

                    <label id="TitleLabel">subject:</label>
                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newMessage.MessageSubject)%>

                    <label id="ContentTextLabel">contents:</label>
                     <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newMessage.MessageContents)%>

                    <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.parentMessageID, 0) %>


                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                </div>

        </fieldset>


    <%} %>
```

The idea is to capture the above form with this Action (in the home controller):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddForumMessage(ForumMessagesViewModel newMessage)
{
    /* Add new forum message to DB */


    return Forum(0);

}
```

but the `"Forum"` action (which generated the view) always captures it instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Weird.  Look at the generated markup to see if the correct URL is being rendered in the <form> tag.

Also, try the alternative:

```
<% Html.BeginForm("..", ".."); %>

<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

Comment: markup is correct (correct action appears in form header in the html source), and the alternative didn't help :-(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've already solved this since it is long ago, but maybe someone else has the same issue.

I just ran into the same problem, also with creating a forum, my quickreply action kept getting picked up by my forum or thread action. All I did was swap around some routes, put the thread and forum ones to a lower position, and that did the trick.

Hope that helps,

Lauw